# How do you setup python3.2 on ubuntu 14.04 for testing with tox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tox

Trying to use tox to run tests before pushing, but I keep running into errors like:

```
ERROR:   py26: InterpreterNotFound: python2.6
ERROR:   py32: InterpreterNotFound: python3.2
ERROR:   py34: InterpreterNotFound: python3.3
```

apt-cache search isn't offering any packages that look like they will help.  How do you load all these versions of the interpreter for ubuntu14.04?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, Ubuntu doesn't ship all historic versions of Python. But you can use [deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes) which has everything from 2.3 to 3.4.

For one project I used drone.io CI service with, I had the following tox section I ran before actual test envs.

```
[testenv:setupdrone]
whitelist_externals = /bin/bash
commands            =
  bash -c "echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select noninteractive' | sudo debconf-set-selections"
  bash -c "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes &> /dev/null"
  bash -c "sudo apt-get update &> /dev/null"
  bash -c "sudo apt-get -y install python2.6 python3.4 &> /dev/null"
```

Comment: I find it strange they don't ship a larger selection of Python's considering what some people have in production.  But thanks for the info.  I'll give it a try when I get back from vacation.